# Using top in a subquery

Tags: t-sql

I have the following data structure and I want to write a query that returns for a given order number, all the orderlineid's with the most recent statusId for that orderline.

[image]

If I was just interested in a particular order line I could use

```
select top 1 StatusId from task where OrderLineId = @OrderLineId order by TaskId desc
```

but I can't figure out how to get all the results for a given OrderId in one SQL Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use `row_number` in a subquery:

```
select orderid, orderlineid, statusid
from (
    select o.orderid, 
           ol.orderlineid, 
           t.statusid, 
           row_number() over (partition by o.orderid order by t.taskid desc) rn
    from order o
        join orderline ol on o.orderid = ol.orderid
        join task t on ol.orderlineid = t.orderlineid
    ) t
where orderid = ? and rn = 1
```

Please note, `order` is a reserved word in sql server so if that's your real table name, you'll need to use brackets around it.  But I'd recommend renaming it to make your life easier.

Comment: Oops, I agree that was not a good name for a table.  I put a small database together to illustrate my problem. In the production database the table is called something else.